# Can't use custom provider

Tags: nestjs

I'm trying to inject a custom provider as per the documentation:

https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers

My service:

```
@Injectable({scope: Scope.REQUEST})
export class ReportService implements OnModuleInit {
  private readonly reportRepository: Repository<Report>;

  constructor(
    public config: ConfigService,
    private readonly moduleRef: ModuleRef,
    @Inject('CONNECTION') connection: Connection,
  ) {
    console.log(connection);
  }
  ...
```

`app.module.ts`:

```
const connectionProvider = {
  provide: 'CONNECTION',
  useValue: connection,
};

@Module({
  imports: [
    ReportModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [connectionProvider],
  controllers: [AppController],
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
```

Doing so results in:

```
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ReportService (ConfigService, ModuleRef, ?). Please make sure that the argument at index [2] is available in the ReportModule context.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post the code of your module where you're providing the custom provider?

Comment: Added config in `app.module.ts`. Perhaps I need to add config to `ReportModue`?

Comment: Yes, you need to export the provider in your app module and import `AppModule` into the modules that want to use them. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a `provider` should be available outside of the module you defined it in, you need to add it to `exports` in the module definition (`app.module`). The other module (`report.module`) using it needs to add the module to its `imports` definition.

**app.module.ts**

```
const connectionProvider = {
  provide: 'CONNECTION',
  useValue: Connection,
};

@Module({
  imports: [
    ReportModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [connectionProvider],
  exports: ['CONNECTION'],
  controllers: [AppController],
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {}
```

**report.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    AppModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  controllers: [],
})
export class ReportModule implements NestModule {}
```

**In your case, this produces a circular dependency which needs to be resolved.**

Since `app.module` seems to be your core module you could make it [global](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules#global-modules) but you still need to export the provider.

Alternatively, I found it to be a good practice to not define any providers in `app.module` and use `DynamicModule` (e.g. `forRoot` and `forFeature` static initiator functions) to only instantiate what is needed, but that seem to be outside of this question.

Comment: Importing `AppModule` from `ReportModule` results in a circular reference.

Comment: That's what my bold text says ;) You can either make the app module global (then it is available without importing it) or restructure the app to not have a circular dependency.

Comment: In case anyone else lands here: I had overlooked the fact that providers are encapsulated by modules; only modules can be exposed globally to the entire application. Thanks to @KenavR I realized that I had to create a stand-alone global "connection" module from which I could export my provider.